# Capturing Page Source (HTML Snapshot) After Angular Templating

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

Quick **angular.js** question...

If I have a webpage with content like this:

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

And I set the model for 'message' such that

```
$scope.message = "Hello world!"
```

Then on the screen, the contents of the div will display as

```
Hello world!
```

But if I view the source in Chrome or Firefox, the source still looks like this

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

Is there any way to capture the source of a page after Angular templating, so when I view the source I see

```
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

For example, if I am working on a project where I am using Angular to help me with the templating but the client would like the final pages in HTML with no angular, how could I capture the HTML of pages after the templating has been applied to give to this client?

Comment: Hi, Did u get any solution for this, If get it, Kindly please guide me...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

https://github.com/cburgdorf/grunt-html-snapshot

This is a grunt task that takes an HTML snapshot of a page: it will run the page in a "fake" or "headless" browser, called phantomjs, do a run of the javascript, then save the rendered HTML for you.

Here are steps to setup Grunt to do this, from nothing:

1. Install node.js from http://nodejs.org - this will install `node` and `npm` (node package manager) for you. Grunt is available on npm.
2. Open your command line and navigate to your project folder.

   - On windows: `cd c:/myprojects/superproject`
   - On mac: `cd /Users/itcouldevenbeaboat/myprojects/superproject`
   - On linux: `i hope you know how to do this already if you use linux :D`
3. Run `npm install -g grunt-cli` to install grunt command line tools globally.
4. Run `npm install grunt grunt-html-snapshot` to install a local copy of all of grunt's needed-to-run-in-a-project filesto your project, and the html snapshot task.
5. Create a super simple Gruntfile.js in your project root with these contents:

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {
     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-snapshot');

     grunt.initConfig({
       htmlSnapshot: {
         all: {
           options: {
             snapshotPath: 'snapshots/',
             sitePath: 'www/index.html', 
             urls: ['#/home', '#/about', '#/users/itcouldevenbeaboat']
           }
         }
       }
     });

     grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlSnapshot']);
   };
   ```
6. Run `grunt` in your project root, and it will take a snapshot :-)

You may need to start your website up on a server first, and set sitePath in the Gruntfile to point to that for it to work properly.

Look at the the [grunt-html-snapshot page](https://github.com/cburgdorf/grunt-html-snapshot) if you need help with the snapshot configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this is obviously a very good and well qualified answer, but I was hoping for something a bit less technical for someone who doesn't know how to use grunt.

Comment: Truly, an answer that goes above and beyond!

Comment: +1 nice.. @Andy Joslin Is there any repo where i can see the list of angular related grunt tasks

Comment: @Andrew Joslin what if i want to do it my using php??

Comment: Hi this one throwing me an Error Like - Aborted due to Warnings. Some one please help me out.

Answer (score 6):

As Langdon said, Chrome will do. I managed to get this done through Chrome's Inspector's "Edit as HTML" option.

First save the page (from now on PAGE_ORIGINAL) as "Webpage, complete". (Saved page will be referred as PAGE_COPY.)

1. Open Chrome and inspect any element on PAGE_ORIGINAL. Inspector will open.
2. Right-click on PAGE_ORIGINAL's source code's **body** tag, choose "Edit as HTML", and copy tag and everything within.
3. Replace **body** and its contents on PAGE_COPY with what you just copied.
4. Remove Angular by deleting references to it on PAGE_COPY.

Worked for me. :-) (I tried commenting on Langdon's answer, but didn't have enough rep.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to "view source" in the traditional sense and see HTML modified by Angular.  That's because view source will show the source from the server and Angular is only making changes to the markup already loaded from the server.

What you want to do is use Chrome's inspector (F12) or FireBug (maybe? does that still exist) in FireFox.  Chrome's inspector and FireBug will show you the "active" source, or how the HTML looks at the time you're viewing it.

Comment: I was able to get some results using this strategy, definately not a bad answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox, simply use the built-in developer tools and select "Inspector". This gives you the current DOM, including changes made by Angular.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement, but I needed the html from within the same browser session. The simple solution was to use element.innerHTML.

(Still thinking it would be nice to get rid of all the ng-* attributes and other angular-specific attributes though.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be certain that your content is ready before the snapshot is taken, [grunt-html-snapshots](http://github.com/localnerve/grunt-html-snapshots) will wait until a selector is visible in the output (using jQuery is(":visible")) before taking the snapshot. Specific snapshot configuration options are found [here](https://github.com/localnerve/html-snapshots/blob/master/README.md).