# Is it possible to save the final HTML output of an Angular 2 app?

Tags: html, angular, save

I have an angular 2 app that is working well. I am now trying, however, to get at the HTML that the app and its components are generating so I can save the result on disk. Is that possible?

Comment: Pretty sure this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524747/capturing-page-source-html-snapshot-after-angular-templating

Comment: @sheplu, I think he is asking for angular not angularjs